# Postgres accessing row values in a FOR loop

Tags: postgresql, loops, rows, variable-assignment, plpgsql

I am novice to Postgres. Here is the structure and some sample data for my **table `job_defn`**:

```
CREATE TABLE job_defn (
        job_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        job_name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
        system CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
        frequency CHARACTER VARYING(10) NOT NULL,
        run_day_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        run_day_of_month INTEGER NOT NULL,
        eff_start_date DATE NOT NULL,
        eff_end_date DATE NOT NULL
    );
```

Sample data:

```
---------------------------
job_id         frequency
---------------------------
1001           DAILY 
1002           WEEKLY
---------------------------
```

When running the following **function**, I was expecting the `l_freq` variable to contain `frequency` column value from the table. However, it is always printing NULL even though the table row contains a value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testing()
   RETURNS void AS $$
   DECLARE

       l_job_id INTEGER;
       l_job_defn_record job_defn%ROWTYPE;
       l_freq CHARACTER VARYING(10);
   BEGIN
       FOR l_job_defn_record IN 
               SELECT job_id, frequency FROM job_defn ORDER BY job_id ASC
       LOOP
               l_job_id := l_job_defn_record.job_id;
               l_freq := l_job_defn_record.frequency;
               raise info'job id: %,  frq: %', l_job_id, l_freq;
               raise info'row==>%', l_job_defn_record;

       END LOOP;
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

**Log:**

```
17:50:52  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.036 secs]  Command processed. No rows were affected
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10001,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10001,DAILY,,,,,,,,,,)
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10001,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10001,DAILY,,,,,,,,,,)
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10001,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10001,DAILY,,,,,,,,,,)
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10001,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10001,DAILY,,,,,,,,,,)
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10001,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10001,DAILY,,,,,,,,,,)
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10001,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10001,DAILY,,,,,,,,,,)
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10001,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10001,DAILY,,,,,,,,,,)
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- job id: 10002,  frq: <NULL>
Code: 0 SQL State: 00000 --- row==>(10002,WEEKLY,,,,,,,,,,)
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.036/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 warnings, 0 errors]
```

Comment: The function seems ok, the problem may be with the type of columns. Edit the question and add the table definition (`\d job_defn` in psql)

Comment: Hi klin, I have added table definition. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the record variable `l_job_defn_record` as type `job_defn%ROWTYPE`. As you later clarified, the table `job_defn` actually consists of more than just the two columns you first disclosed. The assignment in the `FOR` loop only assigns the ***first two fields*** of the record variable:

```
...
   FOR l_job_defn_record IN 
      SELECT job_id, frequency FROM ...  -- wrong!
...
```

This way, the 2nd column from the `SELECT` query (`job_defn.frequency`) is assigned to the 2nd field of the record variable (`l_job_defn_record.job_name`) - obviously not as intended. It happens to work since `frequency` is also be type `varchar`. Trailing fields of the record are not assigned and default to `NULL`.

This would fix it:

```
...
   FOR l_job_defn_record IN 
      SELECT * FROM job_defn ORDER BY job_id
...
```

Often, `SELECT *` is suspicious coding, but in this case it is the proper way since `l_job_defn_record` has the same row type as the table `job_defn` by definition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, suggested change fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Erwin clearly explained the cause of the error in his answer. I would suggest using [the `RECORD` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) for the variable, instead of `ROWTYPE`.

```
    l_job_defn_record RECORD;
```

The actual structure of such a variable is defined dynamically when a value is assigned to it. Therefore there is no possibility of incompatibility between the variable and the assigned value.

Comment: Thank you very much, suggested change fixed it :)